# &gt; not being urldecoded

Tags: cakephp, get, urldecode

I have a cakephp advanced search form
sending params like array of fields,operators and values
inshort i have an arrays like

```
$fields = array('name','age','class');
$operators = array('==','&gt;=','&gt;'); // &gt; = >
$values = array('alex','21','3');
```

I want to make single array from these 3 arrays as

```
if($operators[$i] == "=="){
   $conditions[$fields[$i]]=$values[$i];
}elseif($operators[$i] == "LIKE"){
   $conditions[$fields[$i]." LIKE"] = "%".$values[$i]."%";
}else{
   //having problem here with urldecode.
   $conditions[$fields[$i]." ".urldecode($operators[$i])] = $values[$i];
}
```

I expect `age >=` but it gives `age &gt;=`
how to resolve this

Comment: Hi, urldecode != html_entity_decode

Comment: please use this "&#60;" for less then and grater then "&#62;

Comment: try using htmlspecialchars_decode($operators[$i]))

Comment: You should be using CakeDC seach plugin instead ( https://github.com/CakeDC/search ). Then you would actually use an advanced search where this is all included, so you need just one single line of configuration. Using it with querystrings also fixes the encoding problem - by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` function instead of `urldecode()`